# Tomcat 6 logging date

Tags: linux, tomcat

My predecessor set up Tomcat 6 on a RHEL5 server and it's logging to /var/log/tomcat  and creating log files like catalina.2012-11-28.log (catalina.date.log) - how do I change the log format from date to catalina.1.log, catalina.2.log, etc.?  The server.xml does not contain any references to logging, the only place I see is in logging.properties.  How do I change the behaviour of Tomcat's logging?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of the documentation of the FileHandler : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html

There is possible to specify a generation number with the parameter "%g" in the file ${catalina}/conf/logging.properties.

example :

```
1catalina.java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/catalina.%g.log
```

See also : 
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2014609